# Using renderdoc, how do I find the winding of a triangle in the mesh viewer?

Tags: opengl, vulkan, renderdoc

I feel really stupid asking this, but I can't seem to find any way to figure this out.

I was having issues with my render pass in Vulkan and eventually tracked it to the winding (clockwise vs counterclockwise).

After having slapped my forehead far too hard, I then tried to figure out what the windings of the triangles were in the RenderDoc MeshViewer so that I wouldn't screw this up again.

This is such a fundamental thing that I'm clearly missing the obvious.  I have Googled and searched the docs, but the only thing I found was something on the programmatic interface, and nothing in the GUI itself.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just look at the _output_ (since the winding isn't a property of the triangle, but of the 2D _projection_ of the triangle, so all transformations / operations applied in the shaders will matter). You can easily click through 3 vertices of a triangle in the output, and see where the vertex lights up (enable "highlight vertex").

Comment: Thanks, @zezanjee, that's exactly what I needed to know.   But why didn't you actually answer the question rather than make a comment?

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski I tend to make a comment when the answer is too short even though I shouldn't. I added the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in PipelineState->Rasterizer->RasterizerState->Front CCW.